# not able to set replication for "docker" repository on replica server

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

I have replica and master Artifactory server. I have set replication successfully for many different packages (maven, npm, bower etc.).
I am having difficulties to set pull replication for docker repository on my replica server.

I am able to list the URL with repository structure and its folders in web browser:

```
http://af.domain:8081/artifactory/front-docker
```

This lists a folders which I have in that repo. I am using the admin user to access.
However if I try to set this URL in JFROG Artifactory UI I am getting the message:

```
Connection failed: Error 404: Not Found
```

I have found this link as well:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Smart+Remote+Repositories#SmartRemoteRepositories-Configuration
which implies that I should use `/api/docker` as prefix before the repository key.

```
http://af.domain:8081/artifactory/api/docker/front-docker
```

with this URL I am getting:

```
Connection failed: Error 403: Forbidden
```

I tried also:

`http://af.domain:8081/api/docker/front-docker`
but again I get error 404.
I have set admin credentials on **Advanced** tab. That is the admin user on master server which I am using for all other replications so the permissions should not be the issue.

In logs I do not see anything.

What else can I try?

Answer (score -1):

The needed URL for pull replication is "http://af.domain:8081/artifactory/api/docker/front-docker" and the reason you are getting 403 is the forbidden issue, so add the admin to confirm if 403 is indeed a forbidden/permission issue.

Comment: Hi Muhammed  thank you for your involvement-can you please clarify the last sentence: "so add the admin to confirm if 403 is indeed a forbidden/permission issue" -- can you please provide more details? I am using the admin account for connecting so it should have maximum level of permissions... please explain in more details what I need to do. Thanks

Comment: can you please assist? Thanks

Comment: sorry, I mean pass the admin credentials for testing it out. When you setup a pull replication, you create a smart remote repository by passing this URL "http://af.domain:8081/artifactory/api/docker/front-docker" and in credentials section pass the admin credentials to confirm if this 403 is actually a permission issue.

Comment: I already set the admin credentials in Advanced tab. I have mentioned that already in my question: `I have set admin credentials on Advanced tab`. With same credentials when I want to access through the browser I am login successfully.

Comment: it could be a license issue then. In the target Artifactoy where you are trying to create the pull replication, test out the connection where it fails with 403 and check the artifactory-service.log file for any errors or warnings.

Comment: it's not license issue... As I mentioned for all other packages pull replication is working perfectly fine... also I mentioned I do not see anything in the log files... I already did everything which you suggested... It seems you have not read my question carefully at all... thanks in any way